# 'ping' uses localhost instead of public IP address

Tags: networking, routing, wget, ping, tcpdump

Let's say my server has IP address `11.22.33.44` and hostname `server1.mydomain.com`.

When I ping `server1.mydomain.com`, it looks as if ping is actually using the public IP address:

```
# ping server1.mydomain.com
PING server1.mydomain.com (11.22.33.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server1.mydomain.com (11.22.33.44): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.014 ms
64 bytes from server1.mydomain.com (11.22.33.44): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.012 ms
64 bytes from server1.mydomain.com (11.22.33.44): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.011 ms
```

But with `tcpdump`, I can see no [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) traffic on `eth0` and instead see the pings coming through `lo`:

```
# tcpdump -i lo
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
08:43:49.076918 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo request, id 8525, seq 1, length 64
08:43:49.076931 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 8525, seq 1, length 64
08:43:50.075913 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo request, id 8525, seq 2, length 64
08:43:50.075924 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 8525, seq 2, length 64
08:43:51.074911 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo request, id 8525, seq 3, length 64
08:43:51.074919 IP server1.mydomain.com > server1.mydomain.com: ICMP echo reply, id 8525, seq 3, length 64
```

This behaviour is not limited to `ping`. I get the same with `wget`.

Why is this happening? Is this something caused by the configuration on my server?

I am using [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch).

**EDIT**: to clarify some disagreements that arose in the comments:

I would not mind so much if, when pinging my own public IP address, the traffic actually went to `127.0.0.1`. But then, ping should be honest and actually show it is pinging localhost. What I find treacherous, is that I am pinging `11.22.33.44`, which according to `ifconfig` is associated with `eth0`, and ping pretends it sends traffic to `eth0`, but actually sends to `lo`.

Comment: This is correct behaviour. There's no need for the machine to send packets destined for itself via the Ethernet NIC, so it doesn't.

Comment: @roaima - I disagree. It is not up to the network stack to decide what is "needed". I have clearly specified I want to ping the IP address associated with `eth0`. If I had wanted to ping localhost, I would have used `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: You wanted to ping the **machine** at 11.22.33.44 (or server1.mydomain.com) and you did... The interface is irrelevant in your case because your packet does not need to be routed.

Comment: @std_unordered_map - it is not irrelevant !!! it is being blocked by my current firewall rules

Comment: You may block all the exits in or out of your "room", but it won't stop you from reaching your "room" if you are already there...

Comment: @std_unordered_map - my firewall for `eth0` is open from the outside, anybody can ping, but I cannot because traffic goes to `lo`. So I am not sure what you were trying to say.

Comment: Physically, if it actually went out on `eth0` it wouldn't be received, an Ethernet interface doesn't "hear" what it's sending. So in any case, there needs to be a shortcut somewhere that says "oh this is a local packet, it must be handled locally". Probably easier to redirect the packet to `lo0` than adding a "handle outbound traffic as inbound path", though one would have to check the relevant RFCs for correctness.

Comment: @Martin Vegter - With that analogy I was trying to explain, that your firewall or routing table (and therefore the interface) is not relevant, because there is no reason to consult any of them. You are already at your destination. And constructing the paket and "sending" it through lo is the kernel way to generate some observable effect that anything was happening.

Comment: @MartinVegter you *did* ping the IP address associated with eth0. The packets were sent and delivered to that address, as your tcpdump clearly shows. They were just delivered through the best/shortest available route. (Not to mention, the only one that actually *works*, as mentioned by jcaron; sending packets to yourself on an ethernet is futile as there's no one with your address to receive them...)

Comment: @MartinVegter: Are you saying you have firewall rules on lo?  Why?

Comment: Understanding of notion of [Host Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) can be beneficial in this case.

Comment: @MartinVegter _"It is not up to the network stack to decide what is "needed"."_ - It actually is. If you have multiple network interfaces (usually the case if you count `lo`), the network stack needs to decide which interface to use to send the packets. Also, the network stack needs to decide which interface - and destination MAC address - to use for packets destined outside your local networks, such as the internet. This is called "routing", and it's a crucial part of a network stack.

Comment: @MartinVegter The ping packets are **not** sent to `127.0.0.1` and the `lo` interface is not involved at all. What a host should do with a packet is always determined by the routing table. If you run the command `ip route show table local` you will probably see a line like `local 11.22.33.44 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 11.22.33.44`. This is the most specific route to the address `11.22.33.44` and it tells that this route has scope `host`, i.e. the packets should not leave the host, which makes sense because that's where the packets are destined.

Comment: @Johan Myréen - thank you, `ip route show table local` indeed shows exactly the line as you say. However, regarding your comment that `lo` is not involved that cannot be right. As I said in my original post, I can see the packets with `tcpdump -i lo`

Answer (score 9):

The kernel knows "it is already there" and therefore "optimizes" the sending of the ICMP-packets. Thats why you see them on the loopback-interface. Someone else may be able the fill in more details.

Nevertheless: I had a similar problem some ages ago and I was able the solve them by creating a new network-namespace with `unshare` like `unshare -n /bin/bash`. Then you have a shell with an entire new network-stack (I lack the correct term for that) and without a loopback-interface. You have to define a new IP, routes etc pp. in that, but from that shell you are able to send ICMP-packets to yourself out of the ethernet-interface.

Comment: actually that new network namespace does have (only) a loopback interface, but it's down by default

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how network routing happens on linux. You can look at your routing table, for example, and it will most likely say that any traffic that falls under the 11.22.33.0/24 subnet is going to be routed "locally". This means it will just go straight to loopback.

```
[jar@coffee ~]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.107.136.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.107.136.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Having *10.107.136.0* in the **Destination** column means any traffic on the local subnet should be sent to the listed **Gateway**, which is *0.0.0.0* -- which in this case means route locally.

Having *0.0.0.0* in **Destination** means traffic going anywhere outside this subnet. The default gateway is then listed in **Gateway**

You'll also notice if you run **tcpdump** with the **-n** switch, that the IP address is **not** 127.0.0.1, it just happens to be showing up on the loopback interface because it is local traffic.